# Python script to import CSV to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, import, subprocess

I am writing a python script and I would like to use `subprocess.run()` to import a `.csv` that I have cleaned into a postgresql database but I am unsure of the formatting of the postgresql copy command.

This is my script:

```
def import():
    subprocess.run("c:\\PostgreSQL\\9.6\\bin\\psql.exe" --command " "\\copy public.reports_data (name, date, email) FROM 'C:/DevProj/proj1/cleandata/201707~_cleaned.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';"")
```

There are obviously way to many quotes but the postgresql docs that I have found point to this being the way to us COPY to import data. How should I write the import command so subprocess.run will execute it?

Comment: Why do you want `subprocess`? Why not Psycopg's `copy_from`?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto The honest answer is that I did not know Psycopg could do this, my fault for not reading carefully. Thanks and I will try this. Looks easy  enough and researching it on Stack once I knew what to ask was easy as well. I will try this and upvote.